# A script that uses data from another file to edit an xml file

Tags: python, xml, perl, scripting

I'm pretty inexperienced with scripting so I really need your help on this one.
I have an xml file where every odd line I have this:

```
<![CDATA[<head>Wallpaper</head><body>1328758083110.jpg</body>]]></photo>
```

I'd like to be able to edit each "Wallpaper" part in between the head tags to instead say something pulled from a text file where each element is separated by a line break.

It's a pretty broad question, so I'd appreciate any input at all. Where should I start?

Comment: Why is there markup in a CDATA section?

Comment: Never mind, I just figured it out: "Namespaces are too hard!"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this python snippet should work... I'm assuming there are the same number of lines in your text file as there are lines you want edited in the XML file, and the string "Wallpaper" isn't in any of the lines that you don't want edited. Otherwise you may need something different:

```
inFile = open('mytextfile.txt','r')

myTextData = []
for line in inFile:
    myTextData.append(line.strip())
inFile.close()

inFile = open('myXMLfile.xml','r')
outFile = open('myFinishedXMLfile.xml','w')
currentItem = 0
for line in inFile:
    if 'Wallpaper' not in line:
        outFile.write(line)
    else:
        left = line.find('Wallpaper')
        right = left + 9    # Wallpaper is 9 characters
        outFile.write(line[:left])
        outFile.write(myTextData[currentItem])
        outFile.write(line[right:])
        currentItem += 1
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. This script almost works, but it seems to only be reading from line 1 of mytextfile.txt. So it's inserting in place of "wallpaper" the same string of text for every instance of "wallpaper" instead of moving down the text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -lpe'
    BEGIN { open $file, "<", "text-file-with-substitutions"; }
    if (/Wallpaper/) {
        chomp(my $subst = readline $file);
        s/Wallpaper/$subst/
    }
' xml-file-with-cdata
```